# Solr installation problems on PHP Server (for Drupal)

Tags: linux, solr, drupal-7, shared, boot

I just installed Solr on Drupal 7 and now I am trying to run Solr on my server.

when I entered this:-

`java -jar start.jar` to start Solr, it gave me this error:-

```
If 'java' is not a typo you can run the following command to lookup the package that contains the binary:
    command-not-found java
-bash: java: command not found
```

I checked if java is installed by typing `which java`

for which it says:-

```
which: no java in (/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/root/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/games:/usr/lib/mit/bin:/usr/lib/mit/sbin)
```

### My question is:-

1. How can I install and Run Solr under these circumstances
2. How can I automatically start Solr after server is restarted in future?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install [Java SE 7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) first before anything else. I recommend installing both JRE and JDK.

I am sure there are guides for you distro on the internet.